# The circle is not showing up in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The circle is not showing up. I have the class "Circle" with some methods inside as you can see in my code.

I have no issues with method get_area and get_perimeter. But I got an error stating "plot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ec'".

```py
class Circle:
    from shapely.geometry import Point

    def __init__(self, c1, c2, radius, name):

        self.name = name
        self.c1 = c1
        self.c2 = c2
        self.radius = radius

    def get_area(self):

        PI = 3.142
        return PI * (self.radius * self.radius)

    def get_perimeter(self):

        PI = 3.142
        perimeter = 2 * PI * self.radius
        return perimeter

    def plot(self):

        circle = plt.Circle((self.c1, self.c2), self.radius)
        return circle

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch

newcircle = Circle(0,0,1,'Wonderful')
fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(16,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
newcircle.plot(ax,ec="#ff0000",drawlabel=True)
```

I am expecting it will plot the perfect circle within the axis. Appreciate if you guys could assist me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: You supply an argument to a function which does not expect this argument. Remove `ec` and `drawlabel` from the function call, and you'll be fine. Or let `plot` take those arguments.

Comment: @MohdFairuz, I am trying to run your code, and I am getting an error that `newcircle` is not defined.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf hi there, apologize for that. I've added the newcircle.

Comment: @MohdFairuz, why are you using a custom class `Circle`, when there is a `Circle` class in `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Comment: Hi @lmiguelvargasf, I was instructed to created the custom Circle class constructed by the coordinates of the center and a radius. In this class, I should inherit a proper shapely class. This class will also has one attribute called "name".

Comment: @MohdFairuz, I got you. I was imagining something like that. I have updated my answer, so I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last reply, I think the following code will solve your problems:

```
from math import pi

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point


class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, radius, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(c1, c2)
        self.name = name
        self.radius = radius

    def get_area(self):
        return pi * self.radius ** 2

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return 2 * pi * self.radius

    def plot(self):
        polygon = self.buffer(self.radius)
        return Polygon(np.array(polygon.exterior))


circle = Circle(0, 0, 1,'Wonderful')
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
ax.add_patch(circle.plot())
plt.show()
```

This will produce the following graph:

[image]

I will leave you as a task to fix the axis.